# Flash extend multiple classes

Tags: flash, events, inheritance, extends

I encountered a problem, because I need to be extending MovieClip and EventDispatcher as well to catch events. But I have no idea how to do it.

Here is my class:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Character extends MovieClip //need to extend EventDispatcher as well
    {   

        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
        addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);                
    var PressedKeys:Array = new Array();
        public function update()
        {
              //.....
        }

        private function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            PressedKeys[event.keyCode] = true;
            trace("Keycode: " + event.keyCode + " is: " + PressedKeys[event.keyCode]);
        }

        private function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            PressedKeys[event.keyCode] = false;
            trace("Keycode: " + event.keyCode + " is: " + PressedKeys[event.keyCode]);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding your event listeners is not executed since you have not placed the code in a function.

Try adding your event listeners to your class constructor:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Character extends MovieClip //need to extend EventDispatcher as well
    {   
        private var PressedKeys:Array = new Array();

        public function Character()
        {
            addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
            addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);
        }

        public function update()
        {
            //.....
        }

        private function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            PressedKeys[event.keyCode] = true;
            trace("Keycode: " + event.keyCode + " is: " + PressedKeys[event.keyCode]);
        }

        private function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            PressedKeys[event.keyCode] = false;
            trace("Keycode: " + event.keyCode + " is: " + PressedKeys[event.keyCode]);
        }
    }
}
```

ActionScript does not feature multiple inheritance - only single inheritance of base classes.

However, `MovieClip` already extends `EventDispatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually extend multiple classes in AS3, but `MovieClip` inherits from `EventDispatcher` already, so that shouldn't be a problem in this case.

If you're finding your event listeners aren't triggering, it's probably because your `MovieClip` doesn't have focus. To listen for keyboard events globally, you just need to add the listeners to the `Stage` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your listeners out of the scope of the class anyway so even though they don't produce error they have no effect since they don't even point to an instance of that class.